# How to stream a file in aws lambda using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I am uploading an evidence file to stripe using filestream but apllication was hosted in aws lambda which is not supporting filestream.

Here is my code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile(D.StripeFilePurpose stripeFilePurpose)
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];

            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(
                file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

            var path = string.Empty;
            var webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(webRootPath))
            {
                path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            }

            string fileId;

            var filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);


            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {

                var stripeFileUpload = await _stripeDisputeService
                     .UploadFileAsync(
                         fileName,
                         stream,
                         stripeFilePurpose.GetDescription());

                fileId = stripeFileUpload.Id;

            }

            return StatusCode(200, fileId);
        }
```

whenever specifying a filepath lamba was appending it with /var/task/**mypath.

I even hardcoded filepath still appending /var/task before file path. I searched and found that streaming is possible only if we store file in /tmp folder(lambda)..

How to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a MemoryStream instead.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile(D.StripeFilePurpose stripeFilePurpose)
    {
        IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];

        var fileName = file.FileName.Trim('"');
        using MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        await file.CopyToAsync(memStream);
        memStream.Position = 0;


        var stripeFileUpload = await _stripeDisputeService
                 .UploadFileAsync(
                     fileName,
                     memStream,
                     stripeFilePurpose.GetDescription());

        fileId = stripeFileUpload.Id;



        return StatusCode(200, fileId);
    }
```

It will consume more memory in the service, but avoid disk usage.